# Pipenv just keep locking depedencies and don't finish

Tags: python, pipenv, pipenv-install

There is a lot of time since last time I deployed an app that I maintain, and in the last time I not saved the Pipfile.lock and some depedencies in my Pipfile have specific version and others have just a `"*"` symbol. Now When I try to run `pipenv shell` and `pipenv install` I stuck in a message on cmd `Locking...` and it nevers ends.

I think some compatibility problem is happening but I don't know how to solve. This is a example of some depedencies:

```
urllib3 = "==1.24.1"
wrapt = "==1.10.11"
Django = "==2.2.8"
Wand = "==0.5.2"
django-extensions = "*"
loguru = "*"
ipython = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"
```

Since I don't have the Pipfile.lock what is the best approach in this case? set all dependencies to `"*"`?